# ComboBox item Highlights 2 items in xaml windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am using combobox with 40 items which will open in flyout, after selecting a item the flyout closes and if i try to select different item the flyout opens with highlighting 2 items along with one item which i haven't selected. I tried with altering the style but it didn't work for me.

```
 <ComboBox >
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="One"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Two"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Three"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Four"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Five"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Six"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Seven"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Eight"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Nine"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Ten"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Eleven"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Twelve"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Thirteen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Fourteen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Fifteen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Sixteen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Seventeen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Eighteen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Nineteen"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Twenty"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyOne"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyTwo"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyThree"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyFour"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyFive"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentySix"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentySeven"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyEight"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="TwentyNine"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Thirty"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyOne"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyTwo"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyThree"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyFour"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyFive"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtySix"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtySeven"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyEight"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="ThirtyNine"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>

                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="Fourty"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The problem is with the virtualization of listviewitems(its a bug in the control).

The solution to this is discussed here.

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217063/windows-phone-8-1-combobox-shows-multiple-items-as-selected-when-number-of-items/35449489#35449489)

Hope its helpful.