# windows phone 8.1 music library get current media queue

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, media-player

How to get current media queue in windows phone 8.1 (runtime) as in windows phone 8 MediaPlayer.Queue
Is it available or we have to implement?
Similarly IsShuffled functionality is there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MediaPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx) API belongs to the **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media** namespace which is no longer available for WinRT components. So you can't use it but you can implement your own logic for it using the [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) API which has sufficient properties for a media player except for the logic of queuing etc.

The explanation [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/creating-a-simple-media-player-app-in-metro-style-app-using/) and the [msdn-code-sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be) would surely help you out.

For background music player you should use the  [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdj9zd8ZTLAhUIC44KHZBJB3oQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.aspx&usg=AFQjCNEHhpuuMnxDeRQeQuJQBpH10Fnkcw&sig2=313kL1TQcPxNhXYQwWW1ZA) API and attach the events that occur when your app is running in background.

This [link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/13/the-basics-of-background-audio/) has a background audio explanation. Seems helpful.

Comment: I'm playing the song using BackgroundMediaPlayer

Comment: Then this code sample should help (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319).

Comment: I'm not understanding why Microsoft people removed queue and shuffling feature.

Comment: Great. The code sample has playlist manager example which very much resembles your MediaPlayer.Queue. The reason its removed is that the API was supported by a different framework(XNA) which is dead.

Comment: Yeah it has playlist manager. But it is in different process because background thread will be running in different process. So I have to maintain separate copy of manager in my foreground app. If i shuffle the songs in my background task I wont get the same sequence of songs in my foreground app. That is the reason i asked the question

Comment: Then you should use the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.aspx) API and use this sample here(https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/System-media-transport-7b064ffc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103959/discussion-between-user2354187-and-chirag-shah).

Comment: did you get the solution?  @user2354187

Comment: lets continue in chat

Comment: I hadn't checked the discussion thread, meanwhile I was busy with other work, and I used file to serialize songs info,since LocalSettings has size restrictions..

Comment: can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38073136/base64-string-of-qrcode-is-getting-clipped-when-sent-from-native-windows-phone-a

Comment: link redirects to page not found.

Comment: Yeah. I just deleted the question. I found the solution. :)

Comment: Could you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513094/wp-8-1-wns-push-notification-background-task-is-not-getting-registered-and-pushn